# Send erc20 tokens using the json-rpc api

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, erc-20, golem

I need to send ERC20 tokens (golem to be precise) in an automated manner, so I set up a geth json-rpc server with

`./geth --fast --rpc`

So I can call the api just fine.

The documentation for [eth_sendtransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction) makes it easy to send ethereum to another address, but I couldn't find how to send ERC20 tokens. I saw the data field which allowed to trigger a smart contracts. So I suppose I need to trigger a function within the smart contract of the ERC20 token but since I would need to learn solidity and read through the whole golem smart contract I thought I'd ask here first.

Thanks !

Comment: Since Golem is an ERC20 compliant token, then you need to call the standard `transfer()` function on the smart contract to transfer _x_ tokens to _y_ address.

The function is as follows: `transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)`.

Answer (score 4):

To send ERC20 compliant token you need to call method `transfer` of contract. To do this with geth you correctly have chosen `eth_sendTransaction` RPC Call.

In `data` parameter you should specify ABI-encoded function `transfer` with parameters encoded as described [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI) (ABI-encoded).

To encode parameters you may want to use online tool https://abi.hashex.org. You enter name of function (transfer) and add parameters with types and values. Or you can just paste in token abi and pick function `transfer` in dropdown list "Function type". Here is example of using this tool.

[image]

There is also a [javascript library](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi) to encode parameters if you want to do this automatically.

After you got your ABI-encoded data, you set it to `data` field in Geth RPC call, set other values and you are ready to call Geth and transfer tokens.

Pay attention to that account your are sending tokens from (`from` parameter in RPC call) should be unlocked in Geth to sign transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, tried your method and it did transfer, ETH and not the token. How and where do we define the contract address (so that it knows the ABI belongs to the contract) so that we can send the correct token.

<-- EDIT -->

Just found the solution:
**To:** the address of the token contract, since that's the recipient of the function invocation.

value = 0 (amount of ethereum to be sent.)

Comment: @R Tan, Help me. I am still sending ether. I have updated To as contract address

Answer (score -4):

If you are fine with using a REST API, you could make use of [Chaingateway.io](https://chaingateway.io?utm_source=stackexchange), which allows to automatically send and receive any ERC20 token. This way you don't need to learn Solidity and you can focus on your application.

- I'm not affiliated or paid by Chaingateway, but a happy client since a few months and happy to recommend it.

Comment: Please leave a disclose comment if you are part of Chaingateway team or being paid by them.